# Non hyperelliptic curves of genus 5 form a family of dimension 12

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $C$ is a complete intersection of three quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$, how to count naively the dimension of its parameter spaces? One needs $|O_{\mathbb{P^4}}(2)|=14$ parameters to describe one quadric.

Three general quadrics intersect in a smooth curve, thus the dimension for the choice of three quadrics is $14+14+13$ (the third one should not be in the family of the first two). Then modulo the action of $\operatorname{PGL}_4$. So why is the dimension not $14+14+13-24=17$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $PGL_5$ action is not the only thing to account for: even after fixing our choice of of projective coordinates, there are many distinct choices of quadrics that give not only the same curve up to isomorphism, but the same *embedded* curve, meaning $Q_1 \cap Q_2 \cap Q_3$ is the same subvariety.

Formally, the description you're going for is the construction of a flat rational map

$\mathbb{P}^{14} \times \mathbb{P}^{14} \times \mathbb{P}^{14}\ --> \mathcal{M}_5, \qquad (Q_1, Q_2, Q_3) \mapsto \text{isomorphism class of }Q_1 \cap Q_2 \cap Q_2.$

The fiber of this map for a curve $C$ is given not only by the ($PGL_5$) choice of isomorphism $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{14}}(1)) \to H^0(\omega_C)$, but also by the choice of triple

$$(Q_1, Q_2, Q_3) \in \mathbb{P}H^0(\mathcal{I}_C(2))^{\times3}.$$

Since $H^0(\omega_C(2))$ has 12 sections, $H^0(\mathcal{I}_C(2))$ has at most three sections, hence exactly three. So the fiber above has dimension 6 (as a projective subspace of $(\mathbb{P}^{14})^{\times3}$.)

So the overall count is:

$$14+14+14 - 24 - 6 = 42 - 30 = 12 = \dim \mathcal{M}_5.$$

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I am also stuck on this problem. Could you say a few more words on how you came to subtract 6? I computed the space of complete intersections of three quadrics and arrived at 14+13+12-24=15.

Comment: There are many choices of quadrics that will give the same curve. There is a 3-dimensional vector space of equations of quadrics in the ideal of $C$, i.e. a $\mathbb{P}^2$'s worth of quadrics containing $C$. Then $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3$ can be any general triple of such quadrics, giving 2+2+2 = 6 dimensions of choices.

Comment: The long exact sequence clearly shows that $h^0(\mathcal{I}(2)) \ge 3$, but how do I know equality holds? Is there some obvious reason there cannot be MORE than a $\mathbb{P}^2$ worth? Projective normality would do it...

Comment: Hmmm. The curve is already a complete intersection of three quadrics. Any quadric not in the span of the first three would cut the curve to something strictly smaller.